# how can I parse a specific format of json with SwiftyJSON?

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, swifty-json

In my `swift` app I'm fetching comments from webservice. The general format of incoming json is:

```
comments =     (
            {
        "_id" = 57e460a4d9f58eb150470a0a;
        content = "fsagsd";
        "sent_at" = "2016-09-22T22:52:20.061Z";
        "username" = kamil;
    },
            {
        "_id" = 57e460c0d9f58eb150470a0b;
        content = "hfdhfd";
        "sent_at" = "2016-09-22T22:52:48.682Z";
        "username" = kamil;
    }
);
```

This is an actual result of: `print(response.result.value)`

The whole query (with `alamofire`) looks as follows:

```
Alamofire.request(.GET, "\(serverURL)/get/\(case_id)/comments/"/*, headers: headers*/)
        .validate()
        .responseJSON { response in

switch response.result {
            case .Success:
                print("success")
                if let jsonData = response.result.value as? [[String: AnyObject]] {
                    for myJSON in jsonData {
                        if let myTest = SingleComment.fromJSON(JSON(myJSON)){
                            self.items.addObject(myJSON)
                            self.myTable.reloadData()
                        }
                    }
                }
```

but because the comments are embedded in `comments` in my json - I'm never reaching the `self.items.addObject(myJSON)`. I think it would work if the incoming json looked something like:

```
    {
        "_id" = 57e460a4d9f58eb150470a0a;
        content = "fsagsd";
        "sent_at" = "2016-09-22T22:52:20.061Z";
        "username" = kamil;
    },
            {
        "_id" = 57e460c0d9f58eb150470a0b;
        content = "hfdhfd";
        "sent_at" = "2016-09-22T22:52:48.682Z";
        "username" = kamil;
    }
```

since I cannot change the incoming json - can you please help me to adjust my swift code?

One additional info - the `fromJSON` function is as follows:

```
class func fromJSON(json: JSON) -> SingleComment? {
    print("single comment from json")
    let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"
    let username = json["username"].string
    let content = json["content"].string
    let sent_at = json["sent_at"].string
    let id = json["_id"].string
    let upd = dateFormatter.dateFromString(sent_at!)

    return SingleComment(username: username!, content: content!, sent_at: upd!, id: id!)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code in .Success block. Hope it will help you.

```
    if let value = response.result.value {
                                    let data = JSON(value)
                                    if let responseDictionary = data.dictionary {
                                        if let commentsArray = responseDictionary["comments"]?.array {
                                            for commentObject in commentsArray {
                                                if let myTest = SingleComment.fromJSON(commentObject){
                                                    self.items.addObject(myJSON)

                                                }
                                            }
self.myTable.reloadData()
                                        }
                                    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your response seems not to be a correct json data.

Firstly, json property should be separated by `:`, not `=`. In your example, `"_id" = 57e460c0d9f58eb150470a0b;` should be `"_id" : 57e460c0d9f58eb150470a0b;`.

Secondly, the response data seems to be a jsonp format, since is contains variable and semicolon. But the json format is still not correct. So I think you solution is not to adjust your algorithm to fit such odd `"json"` data, you have to ask your server, why it provide such an odd data.